# Reloading page on react-admin by using javascript-based router

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am wondering if there is a  way to have proper access to  router via javascript. I need to redirect on certain cases, from pure javascript-based methods where I can not use things like [Link components like here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html).

Right now, I am using a method I created:

```
navTo(pageHash){
    window.location.hash = pageHash; // e.g. "#settings"
    window.location.reload(true); 
}
```

But I would like to know if there is another elegant way, e.g. using a router component exposed to the js api.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router

Comment: Thank you Tim, but it doesn't work. No matter where I put the code, I always get: Error: Invalid hook call.

Comment: do you have react-router installed? are you using a functional or class-based approach? check the other answers from this stack overflow post for different solutions